# css or jquery - hover over one div, another div fades or no display

Tags: jquery, css, html, fade

See http://jasondaydesign.com/masonry_demo/

I have title divs that overlay the underlying box div.

What I am trying to accomplish is when the mouse hovers over the .box div, the div holding the title will either fade out with jquery or just display:none through css.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.hover()`, like this: (tested)

```
$('.box:has(div)').hover(
    function() { $(this).find('div').fadeOut(); },
    function() { $(this).find('div').fadeIn(); }
);
```

Comment: what I was typing also - could add a class to the title div if need to differentiate from another div that might not be titles within the box...but that is making an assumption on my part :)

Comment: beautiful. I learn more jquery through the people on this site. Thank you